# "standart" php html form to laravel structure

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have a sample code from a page which is working fine and i want to integrade it to my laravel project. But it i not working. After sumbitting the form it doesnt show anything. This is the code from the page:

HTML

```
<center>
<h3>PHP OCR Test</h3>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</center>

</body>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
    
    echo '<img src="images/'.$file_name.'" style="width:100%">';

    shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe" "C:\\CV-Test\\blog\\public\\images\\'.$file_name.'" out');

       
    $myfile = fopen("out.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("out.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

In Laravel i did the following:

Blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <center>
        <h3>PHP OCR Test</h3>
        <form action="{{route('ocr')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="file" name="image" />
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>


         {{$pic}}
        
        <br><br>

        {{$text}}


    </center>


@endsection
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/OCR', [OcrController::class, 'ocr'])->name('ocr');
Route::post('/OCR', [OcrController::class, 'ocr'])->name('ocr');
```

Controller:

```
class OcrController extends Controller
{

    public function ocr(Request $request)
    {
        $image = $request->input('image');

        $pic = null;
        $text = null;
        if(isset($_FILES[$image])){
            $file_name = $_FILES[$image]['name'];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES[$image]['tmp_name'];

            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);

            $pic = '<img src="images/'.$file_name.'" style="width:100%">';
            shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe" "C:\\CV-Test\\blog\\public\\images\\'.$file_name.'" out');

             $myfile = fopen("out.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $text= fread($myfile,filesize("out.txt"));
            fclose($myfile);


        }

     return view('CV_test.OCR', compact('pic', 'text'));
    }

}
```

When i execute it the form gets posted and no errors, but its simply not showing anything.
It supposed to show the picture first and then the text below which was recognized by the ocr algorithm.
i suspect something with the initializing of the the varibale $pic and $text, but if i dont initilize it i get an error. I dont know how to approach that problem.

Please help me :(

Appriciate.

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on how to [handle uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#files) in Laravel instead of using the `$_FILES` array and manually handle it. Laravel has made it pretty simple and will be much easer. Then you should try one thing at the time. Start with the file upload and get that working. Then you can go on and add the other features, one by one.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment ill check it out. So it mean `$_FILES` is the reason why its not working?

Comment: That's not an issue in itself, but the way you're using it wrong in several places. That's why I would recommend that you do it the "laravel" way and o it one thing at the time. You seem to currently be confusing a lot of concepts.

Comment: Yes i can confirm that i am confused. I am actually new to laravel and there are still a lot of things which are not clear to me. However i am already checking what you said. Thanks dude.

Answer (score -1):

he use a diferrent way for get/move images, maybe can help

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function imageUploadPost(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  

    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.')
        ->with('image',$imageName);

}
```

The blade file:

```
<form action="{{ route('image.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

[Laravel 6 Image Upload Tutorial](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-image-upload-tutorialexample.html)

(For the others users, i cant comment because i dont have 50 of reputation)